# g77 version 3.2 creates large object file with the option -finit-local-zero

Tags: linux, fortran, legacy, numeric, g77

I'm working with a legacy + academic + numerical fortran-77 code that requires g77 3.2.x in order to compile and run successfully ... I'm using that compiler on Red Hat Linux 9 for i386

One of those fortran-77 files defines a subroutine with lots of real, integer, and double precision arrays as local variables ... if I compile it using:

```
$ g77 -c thefile.F -o thefile.o
```

it produces an object file of size around 10kB ... but the following:

```
$ g77 -finit-local-zero -c thefile.F -o thefile.o
```

produces an object file of size 14MB

I tried `strip`'ing the object file but the size doesn't change much

a couple dozen such files in the code and the executable binary ends up being 200MB in size

Any idea about what's going on? more importantly **what can I do to get back to saner object/binary sizes?**

P.S.: when I compressed the 200MB binary into tar.gz, the tarball was under 1 MB ... means probably the 200MB is full of 0's or something (I could open it in a hex-editor but i'm feeling too lazy right now)

P.S.: the compiler details are given below (using the -v flag of g77)

```
$ g77 -v -finit-local-zero -c thefile.F -o thefile.o
Reading specs from /usr/lib/gcc-lib/i386-redhat-linux/3.2.2/specs
Configured with: ../configure --prefix=/usr --mandir=/usr/share/man --infodir=/usr/share/info --enable-shared --enable-threads=posix --disable-checking --with-system-zlib --enable-__cxa_atexit --host=i386-redhat-linux
Thread model: posix
gcc version 3.2.2 20030222 (Red Hat Linux 3.2.2-5)
 /usr/lib/gcc-lib/i386-redhat-linux/3.2.2/tradcpp0 -lang-fortran -v -D__GNUC__=3 -D__GNUC_MINOR__=2 -D__GNUC_PATCHLEVEL__=2 -D__GXX_ABI_VERSION=102 -D__ELF__ -Dunix -D__gnu_linux__ -Dlinux -D__ELF__ -D__unix__ -D__gnu_linux__ -D__linux__ -D__unix -D__linux -Asystem=posix -D__NO_INLINE__ -D__STDC_HOSTED__=1 -Acpu=i386 -Amachine=i386 -Di386 -D__i386 -D__i386__ -D__tune_i386__ thefile.F /tmp/ccXXvzMA.f
GNU traditional CPP version 3.2.2 20030222 (Red Hat Linux 3.2.2-5)
 /usr/lib/gcc-lib/i386-redhat-linux/3.2.2/f771 /tmp/ccXXvzMA.f -quiet -dumpbase thefile.F -version -finit-local-zero -o /tmp/cck0Blw1.s
GNU F77 version 3.2.2 20030222 (Red Hat Linux 3.2.2-5) (i386-redhat-linux)
    compiled by GNU C version 3.2.2 20030222 (Red Hat Linux 3.2.2-5).
 as -V -Qy -o thefile.o /tmp/cck0Blw1.s
GNU assembler version 2.13.90.0.18 (i386-redhat-linux) using BFD version 2.13.90.0.18 20030206
```

EDIT: newer g77/gfortran versions don't have that problem (object file size stays almost the same with -finit-local-zero) but I can't use them (making the code produce correct results with latest compiler versions would be a project in itself) ... and I need the -finit-local-zero flag (code hangs without it)

EDIT 2: I took a hex dump and sure enough 99% of the file consists of zeros!

Comment: Have you tried these options with gfortran, to see if they will get your code to work?: -ffixed-form  -ffixed-line-length-none  -fno-automatic  -finit-local-zero

Comment: @M.S.B. I'll try that and will let u know ... however I'm not too optimistic cz I know the code is badly written with, to say the least, real's and double's mixed together all over the place, with random explicit and implicit conversions ... :(

Comment: I would suggest to try a more recent version of GCC and patch your source code till it fits. GCC 3.2 is very old stuff. Current version is 4.6, with 4.7 appearing in a few months.

Comment: I would also recommend moving to gfortran, then you can add allocatable arrays, because maybe it's static arrays being filled with zeros that cause this huge object size?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the on-line documentation:

http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gfortran/Code-Gen-Options.html

```
-finit-local-zero
-finit-integer=n
-finit-real=<zero|inf|-inf|nan|snan>
-finit-logical=<true|false>
-finit-character=n
    The -finit-local-zero option instructs the compiler to initialize local INTEGER,
    REAL, and COMPLEX variables to zero, LOGICAL variables to false, and CHARACTER 
    variables to a string of null bytes. Finer-grained initialization options are
    provided by the -finit-integer=n, -finit-real=<zero|inf|-inf|nan|snan> (which 
    also initializes the real and imaginary parts of local COMPLEX variables), 
    -finit-logical=<true|false>, and -finit-character=n (where n is an ASCII 
    character value) options. These options do not initialize

    * allocatable arrays
    * components of derived type variables
    * variables that appear in an EQUIVALENCE statement. 

    (These limitations may be removed in future releases).
```

> Q: Any idea about what's going on? and what can I do to get back to
>   saner object/binary sizes?
>
> Means probably the 200MB is full of 0's or something?

A: Yup.  Sounds like you've answered your own question :)

Comment: Yes, all variables are explicitly put in the data segment and their value is 0. And Fortran 77 used only static data.